# Prevent filesystem from synchronizing

Tags: filesystems, ext4, embedded, synchronization, flash-memory

I have an embedded system running Debian with a ext4 file system on eMMC.
If the power goes down, the system has about 1 second to detect and sync the file system before voltage is below threshold and it stops executing.

Currently, a detected low voltage triggers `sync()` followed by `reboot(RB_POWER_OFF)`.

There are cases when the power off is not needed because power comes back after the `sync()` is called.  So I would rather not do the reboot, but wait for the processor to fail because of low voltage, hence being able to continue if power is back.

**Problem:**

Not powering off after `sync` will put other files in queue for being written.  If the OS decides to write them while power goes down the file system will get corrupted.

**Question:**

How can I prevent the OS from doing a synchronization of the file system for a short while?

That would enable the possibility to check if voltage raises above a certain level and continue as usual without the need for poweroff.

Comment: You could remount it as read-only for the time being, is that feasible?

Comment: @Panki It is the root file system and I do not think it is remountable.